# Formatting a JSON with a dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

I have a JSON with format variables in it, similar to string format, and I'd like to be able to load it with the variables replaced by actual values.

For example, if the JSON is:

```
[
    {
        "role": "President",
        "name": "{first_name}",
        "age": "{first_age}"
    },
    {
        "role": "Vice President",
        "name": "{second_name}",
        "age": "{second_age}"
    }
]
```

And the dictionary I'd like to format with is:

```
{"first_name": "Bob", "first_age": "50", "second_name": "Bill", "second_age": "35"}
```

I'd like to get:

```
[
    {
        "role": "President",
        "name": "Bob",
        "age": "50"
    },
    {
        "role": "Vice President",
        "name": "Bill",
        "age": "35"
    }
]
```

I tried converting the JSON to a string, using format, and then turning it back to a list of dictionaries:

```
from ast import literal_eval
literal_eval(str(raw_json).format(**json_params))
```

But the dictionaries' curly brackets confuse the format function and give me a KeyError exception. I suppose I could replace every pair of curly brackets which don't have a variable name between them with double curly brackets, but that's bound to go wrong and also not very Pythonic.

What would be the most elegant way to solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a templating engine.
Template is json string and data must be injected into this template.
Right tool to do that with python is [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/)